# ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool given rails 3.1.1

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am getting this strange error

> superclass must be a Clas(ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool given)

when trying to deploy. Otherwise my app is working great on local machine. What might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

We generally use Connection pool base class for managing Active Record database connections.

A connection pool synchronizes thread access to a limited number of database connections.

This [DOC](http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.1.1/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool) will help put light to your problem and how to fix it!!